# Hyphenation in two languages in XeLaTeX + polyglossia

Tags: xetex, hyphenation

I am fairly new to LaTeX so please excuse any obvious parts of the question.

I am looking for a way to setup hyphenation in 2 languages (Greek and English) at the same time. My setup is MacTeX +Texmaker+ XeLaTeX + polyglossia. The main language is Greek and I periodically use some terms in English that escape the fully justified text body.
Concerning the language, my preamble looks like:

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont[]{Cambria} 
\setsansfont[]{Candara} 
\setmonofont[]{Consolas} 

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
```

I would also appreciate any comments for my preamble on commands I could omit or change.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you input the English terms?

Comment: If i get your q right, i don't use a special command. I just change my keybord language. Do you suggest to use a command for those terms, indicating language change, like \textlatin{ }?

Comment: for a single phrase I suggest `\foreignlanguage{english}{text in English}`

Comment: That gives a solution to the problem, indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to get correct English hyphenation in your setup is to use `\foreignlanguage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Candara}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

Αυτό το κείμενο είναι στα ελληνικά
\foreignlanguage{english}{and not in English}

\end{document}
```

You may want to define a shorthand in the preamble, such as

```
\newcommand{\EN}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
```

so the input can be

```
Αυτό το κείμενο είναι στα ελληνικά
\EN{and not in English}
```

Note that loading `xltxtra` is not recommended any more. The most recent versions of `fontspec` take care of what used to be delegated to `xltxtra`, including the default font features.